# How to fix 'Could not proxy command to remote server. Original error: Error: socket hang up' issue when scrolling in appium?

Tags: java, appium

I tried to scroll iOS application using appium, this error occurs as when the scroll finishes.

I use a real iOS device as an emulator.
appium v1.13
java client v6.1.0

Code for scroll:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
HashMap<String, String> swipeObject = new 
HashMap<String, String>();

swipeObject.put("direction", "up"); // up for swipe
js.executeScript("mobile: scroll", swipeObject);
```

Full error message:

```
Encountered internal error running command: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not proxy command to remote server. Original error: Error: socket hang up
```

After the scrolling all the way to the bottom, one button needs to be clicked. but this scrolls all the way to the bottom and exit with this error.

Comment: Haven't seen solved issues related to this. anyone else facing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

you may trap this exception in a try catch block :

```
try{
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
HashMap<String, String> swipeObject = new 
HashMap<String, String>();

swipeObject.put("direction", "up"); // up for swipe
js.executeScript("mobile: scroll", swipeObject);
}catch(exception e)
{
}

button.click() ;
```

This way the exception happens but your test will continue without failing your execution.